# can't fix CSS Layout overflow

Tags: css, html

I am trying to style the layout I will use as a template for my site and after a lot of reading I came up with this:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/login.css" />
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            Main
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper{
    height: 100%;
}

#header{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#main{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Seems to be working but for some reason the wrapper and the main div seem to take the exact same height and this makes the page grow larger than the window and scrolling down is needed to see the footer.

I tried a lot of stuff to fix this including CSS absolute positioning and I have been using different browsers to test it.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because you set height:100%; in your #main set is to 100px or something else and it will work

Comment: yeah but I did that because I need the header and footer always at the top and bottom respectively, even when the content is not as big as the window.

Answer (score 0):

I would really like to suggest you look at using something like bootstrap grid..
It will make you layout life so much easier across all browsers..

you just create a container with rows, and add divs with certain spans in them and it aligns everything perfect.

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="header">
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="body">
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="footer">
  </div> 
</div>
```

done :)

Further reading, takes like 10-15 min to figure out, then say goodbye to css nightmare..

http://www.revillwebdesign.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Answer (score 0):

First, put the `link` tag in the `head` section of the HTML document not in the body section.

As far as the css, I would not set heights on elements.  Instead, only set the height if absolutely necessary.  Let the content, padding and margin push the footer down to the appropriate height.